# Windows 8 missing glyphs / icons

Tags: windows-8, fonts, icons

So recently I installed few fonts on my system inorder to design few banners in photoshop so I bulk installed them and when system prompted to replace the existing fonts, I replaced them. Now am not sure what exactly happened here, and which font is causing this...

I am not able to see the icons anymore, all I see is square boxes... Am attaching a screenshot as an example :-

[image: Windows 8 missing glyphs]

On searching over internet I didn't got any specific solution related to this but I did read that I must have installed old version of *Segoe UI Symbol* where I need 5.90 for Windows 8 and 6. something for Windows 8.1

But am not sure whether that's the solution and I don't get any font download (may be it is licensed). So how should I fix this?

Comment: you're correct: http://www.askvg.com/fix-unknown-characters-or-vertical-rectangles-are-showing-in-place-of-metro-icons-in-windows-8-start-screen-and-login-screen/

Comment: @magicandre1981 downloaded and installed both of the font, 8 and 8.1, none worked, I think I need to restore an older copy now... Thanks for the link though...

Comment: extract the font out of the Windows DVD: http://blog.nirsoft.net/2009/09/17/how-to-extract-missing-system-files-from-the-dvd-of-windows-7vista/